# What is wrong with the following VBA code for sorting data in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I need to write a script to sort data in Excel using VBA and macros. The script should look like this:
Check if the value in column A = the value in column D AND the value in column B = the value in column E.

If the values are equal, check the next row.

If the values do not equal, insert new cells and move the values in the cells in columns A, B and C down by 1 position (insert new cells for columns A, B and C ONLY).

After moving the cells in columns A, B and C, check again that the value in column A = the value in column D AND the value in column B = the value in column E. If yes, check the next row, if no, stop the script.

With the help of ChatGPT I was able to generate the following code:

```
Sub SortDataWithInsert()
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim continueSorting As Boolean

    currentRow = 1
    continueSorting = True

    While continueSorting
        ' Get the values from columns A, B, D, and E in the current row
        value_a = Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
        value_b = Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
        value_d = Cells(currentRow, 4).Value
        value_e = Cells(currentRow, 5).Value

        If value_a = value_d And value_b = value_e Then
            ' If values are equal, check the next row
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Else
            ' If values are not equal, insert new cells and shift cells in columns A, B, and C down
            Rows(currentRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            For col = 1 To 3 ' Columns A, B, and C
                Cells(currentRow + 1, col).Value = Cells(currentRow, col).Value
                Cells(currentRow, col).Value = ""
            Next col

            ' After inserting and moving cells, recheck if the values are equal
            value_a = Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
            value_b = Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
            value_d = Cells(currentRow, 4).Value
            value_e = Cells(currentRow, 5).Value

            If value_a = value_d And value_b = value_e Then
                ' If values are equal, continue checking the next row
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            Else
                ' If values are not equal, stop the script
                continueSorting = False
            End If
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

However, the code does not work – the Excel freezes every time. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does it fail? ie which line?

Comment: This looks more like re-arranging data rather than sorting it (you're adding a bunch of blank cells?). Can you please provide sample data for both before (how the data is setup originally) and after (how you expect the results to be after the macro is run).

Comment: Also, likely the reason your Excel is freezing is because you have a potentially infinite loop, with no plan to exit the loop if it encounters a scenario where all a/d and b/e values are equal (which would be true even for blank cells). This is why While/Wend loops are generally frowned upon as bad practice. Hard to give a good alternative without knowing more specifics though.

Comment: This should be looping from the bottom up.

Answer (score 1):

AI is not always right. You have to optimize (or fix) the code.

```vb
Sub SortDataWithInsert()
    Dim currentRow As Long, lstRow As Long
    Dim continueSorting As Boolean
    Dim arr
    currentRow = 1
    continueSorting = True
    Do While Len(Trim(Cells(currentRow, 1))) > 0
        arr = Cells(currentRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value
        If arr(1, 1) = arr(1, 4) And arr(1, 2) = arr(1, 5) Then
            continueSorting = True
        Else
            If Not continueSorting Then Exit Do
            Cells(currentRow, 1).Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            continueSorting = False
        End If
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you only have an exit from your `While` loop when it finds mismatching data.  In other words, if all of your value_a = value_d and all of your value_b = value_e, the `ContinueSorting` variable is never changed to `False` and the loop never exits.   This is why Excel freezes.

You need to add some sort of exit condition for when all of your data is matching.